# What defines a "built-in target" for AWS CloudWatch Events?

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-cloudwatch

In CloudWatch Events' [documentation](http://docs.aws.amazon.com/AmazonCloudWatchEvents/latest/APIReference/API_Target.html) as well as initial [announcement](https://aws.amazon.com/blogs/aws/new-cloudwatch-events-track-and-respond-to-changes-to-your-aws-resources/), there are several possible targets to forward events to, including Lambdas, Kinesis Streams, SNS topics, and **built-in targets**.

What is a built-in target, exactly? In the Console I can see options for EC2 actions, as well as CodeDeploy, but it doesn't make sense why they don't just mention those by name like the others.

Comment: Indeed. This is overly cryptic.